# Как настроить роутинг в проекте?

Tags: angular, маршрутизация, angular-routing

В целях самообучения *angular*, пытаюсь сделать небольшой каталог с телефонами и столкнулся с проблемой:

Имеется модуль **core**, к нему подключен модуль **catalogue** с 2 компонентами (**main-page**(aka вьювер) и **details**. Идея проста - первый забивается мобилками, а при нажатии на детали должна выводиться новая страница с описанием конкретной мобилки. Однако, в моей реализации описание не открывается. Предполагаю, что проблема с роутингом.

Ниже мой код.

**core-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'catalogue',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        loadChildren: '../admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'form',
        loadChildren: '../form/form.module#FormModule'
    },
    {
        path: 'catalogue',
        loadChildren: '../catalogue/catalogue.module#CatalogueModule'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: NotFoundComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CoreRoutingModule { }
```

**catalogue-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MainPageComponent } from './components/main-page/main-page.component';
import { DetailsComponent } from './components/details/details.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: MainPageComponent },
    { path: 'catalogue', component: MainPageComponent },
    { path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CatalogueRoutingModule { }
```

main-page.component.html (кусочек)

```
<div class="col-md-10">
      <ul class="phones">
        <li *ngFor="let phone of phones" class="thumbnail">
          <a [routerLink]="['/details']" routerLinkActive="active" class="thumb">
            <img alt="{{phone.name}}" src="{{phone.imageUrl}}">
          </a>

          <div class="phones__btn-buy-wrapper">
            <a class="btn btn-success">
              Add
            </a>
          </div>

          <a [routerLink]="['/details']" routerLinkActive="active">{{phone.name}}</a>
          <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
        </li>        
      </ul>

    </div>
```

В текущем варианте при клике на ссылку ведущую к деталям ничего не происходит (** в расчет не беру). Будьте так любезны, помогите понять в чем причина. Возможно найдутся пруфы на нужную инфу!

Спасибо!

Comment: потому что ссылка ведет на /details а не на /catalogue/details

Comment: Спасибо, помогло :)